# How can I contribute to OpenSuse/SLES packages?

Tags: linux, opensuse, sles

I've got some improvements for correctness for the tomcat 6 and tomcat 7 packages for SLES. I understand that opensuse is upstream.

Where do I start to contribute back to the package?

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault as it appears to relate to programming. It may be on topic for [Stackoverflow](http://Stackoverflow.com) but please [search](http://Stackoverflow.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The [opensuse dev portal](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Development) should get you started.